# EmEditorで検索履歴を残さない方法

Tags: emeditor

最近の検索の表示数で、履歴の数を変更できると思いますが、
値を0にすることができません。
プライバシー上、検索履歴を残さない方法はありますか？

Answer (score 1):

EmEditor v20.5.912 以上に更新されていることを確認してから、[ツール] メニューの [カスタマイズ] を選択し、[履歴] ページを選択して、[終了時、履歴をクリアする] チェック ボックスを設定して、クリアしたい履歴を選択して OK をクリックしてください。

[image: EmEditor - カスタマイズ - 履歴]

[image: EmEditor - 終了時、履歴をクリア]